# switching between WIFI and GPRS notification on iPhone /

Tags: ios

Is there any default notification or mechanism which can notify that device has switch from WIFI to GPRS or vice versa (iPhone + iPad).

Answer (score 1):

NO there is no default notification or mechanism available for this.
But you can do this very easily by using any of this two method.

1. Use [apple Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) classes.
2. USe [tonymillion's  Reachability](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability/blob/master/iOSReachabilityTestARC/iOSReachabilityTestARC/TMViewController.m) ARC supported classes.

This SO answer will guide [How to check for an active Internet Connection on iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk?answertab=active#tab-top)

In this see point no 8 where he show how to differentiate between network type.

Comment: thanks buddy i am going to try this out and will let you know about end results.

Answer (score 0):

If Reachability will not work for you, istead you can use AFNetworking to check your wifi connection

[AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)